# How to pass props onClicked function in one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set that when I click onClick in the component Albums.js, I get the contents of the component photos.js. Specifically, choosing one album will trigger a photo array from this album using the Photos.js component.

Albums.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './forAlbum.css'

class Albums extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  
    };
    this.onClicks = this.onClicks.bind(this);
  }
   onClicks = () => {

    console.log("lamus");
   }

  render () {
    const albums = this.props.albums.map((album, i) => {
      return (
        <AlbumThumb name={album.name} img={album.photos[0].src} id={i} key={i}  />
      );
    });
    // console.log(albums);
    console.log(this.onClicks);
    return (
        <div className="thumbContainer">{albums}</div>
    )
  }
}

const AlbumThumb = (props) => (
  <div  className="thumb">
    <div className="thumbImgWrap">
      <img src={require('./GalleryImages/' + props.img)} alt={props.name} />
    </div>
    <h3 className="thumbTitle">{props.name}</h3>
  </div>

);

export default Albums;
```

This is Photos.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './forAlbum.css'

const Photos = (props) => {
    const cliced = () => {
        console.log("cliced");
    }
    const photos = props.photos.map(({ photos }) =>
        <div>
            <ul key={photos.id}>
                {photos.id}
            </ul>

            {photos.map((eachThing, i) => {
                return (
                    <PhotoMain name={eachThing.cap} img={eachThing.src} id={i} key={i} />
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
    // console.log(photos);
    return <div className="thumbContainer" onClick={props.clicked}>{photos}</div>;
};

const PhotoMain = (props) => (
    <div className="thumb" >
        <div className="thumbImgWrap">
            <img src={require('./GalleryImages/' + props.img)} alt={props.name} />
        </div>
        <h3 className="thumbTitle">{props.name}</h3>
    </div>
);

export default Photos;
```

But i don't how to connect this, Maybe someone has an idea or suggestion?

I try to invoke this in next component GalleryPhotos.js

```
<Albums albums={data3} onClick={this.onClicks} />
<Photos photos={data3} />

const data3 = [
    {
    id: '1',
    name: "Siatkówka",
    photos: [
        {
            id: "11",
            src: "siatkowka1.jpg",
            cap: "Siatkówka"
        },
        {
            id: "12",
            src: "siatkowka2.jpg",
            cap: "Siatkówka2"
        },
        {
            id: "13",
            src: "siatkowka3.jpg",
            cap: "Siatkówka3"
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: "Piłka nożna",
        photos:[
            {
                id: "21",
                src: "pilkaNozna1.jpg",
                cap: "Piłka nożna1"
            },
            {
                id: "22",
                src: "pilkaNozna2.jpeg",
                cap: "Piłka nożna2"
            },
            {
                id: "23",
                src: "pilkaNozna3.jpg",
                cap: "Piłka nożna3"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

EDIT 1 - filter method

```
const Photos = (props) => {
    const photos = props.photos.filter(photos => photos.id === '1').map(({photos}) => 
        <div>
            <ul key={photos.id}>
            {photos.id} 
            </ul>

            {photos.filter(eachThing => eachThing.id === eachThing.id).map((eachThing, i) =>
            {
            return (
                <PhotoMain name={eachThing.cap} img={eachThing.src} id={i} key={i} />
                    );
            })}
        </div>
    );
    console.log(photos);
    return <div className="thumbContainer">{photos}</div>;
  };
```

I used the Filter.js method and thanks to it I am able to select by identifying the specific album ID, which photos must appear, but I am wondering how to set it as dynamic relative to the component. The biggest difficulty is understanding how the connections between components are made to make this filter effective. In addition, I wonder if the component Albums.js while filtering has something to logic

Edit 2:
Console message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: props.photos.filter is not a function
    at Photos (Photos.js:6)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:14592)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15082)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:17903)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:17944)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:196)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:17224)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:18037)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:18919)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:18826)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:18799)
    at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:19109)
    at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2328)
    at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:5134)

The above error occurred in the <Photos> component:
    in Photos (at GalleryPhotosVideos.js:208)
    in div (at GalleryPhotosVideos.js:204)
    in div (at GalleryPhotosVideos.js:196)
    in CSSTransitionGroupChild (created by TransitionGroup)
    in span (created by TransitionGroup)
    in TransitionGroup (created by CSSTransitionGroup)
    in CSSTransitionGroup (at GalleryPhotosVideos.js:190)
    in GalleryPhotosVideos (created by Route)
    in Route (at Content.js:33)
    in Switch (at Content.js:24)
    in div (at Content.js:23)
    in Content (at App.js:14)
    in div (at App.js:12)
    in App (at src/index.js:10)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:10)

Uncaught TypeError: props.photos.filter is not a function
    at Photos (Photos.js:6)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:14592)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15082)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:17903)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:17944)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:18022)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:18919)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:18826)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:18799)
    at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:19109)
    at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2328)
    at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:5134)


This message I see when  I click
TypeError: props.photos.filter is not a function
const photos = props.photos.filter(photos => photos.id === photos.id).map(({photos}) =>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component containing your Album and Photos should only render the Photos component if a state boolean value is true. When click on your album, this value will be updated :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class ThankYou extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            showPhotos: false
        }
    }

    albumClicked = ev => {
        this.setState({ showPhotos: true })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Albums albums={data3} onClick={this.albumClicked} />
                {this.state.showPhotos && <Photos photos={data3} />}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

And then call the function passed in the album :

```
const AlbumThumb = (props) => (
    <div className="thumb" onClick={ev => {props.onClick()}}> //Calls the parent function when clicked
        <div className="thumbImgWrap">
            <img src={require('./GalleryImages/' + props.img)} alt={props.name} />
        </div>
        <h3 className="thumbTitle">{props.name}</h3>
    </div>
);
```

---

EDIT :

I did not notice that `AlbumThumb` wasn't your component. You will have to move the function up to the `Album` render function (and remove it from `AlbumThumb`) :

```
render() {
    const albums = this.props.albums.map((album, i) => {
        return (
            <div onClick={ev => { props.onClick() }}>
                <AlbumThumb name={album.name} img={album.photos[0].src} id={i} key={i} />
            </div>
        );
    });
    // console.log(albums);
    console.log(this.onClicks);
    return (
        <div className="thumbContainer">{albums}</div>
    )
}
```

---

EDIT 2 :

Filtering albums by owners name :

```
this.props.albums.filter(album => album.name.includes(myFilterString)).map(...
```

---

EDIT 3 :

Your parent class will have to be aware of wich album got selected, you will have to send your album data back to it using the onClick function :

```
const albums = this.props.albums.map((album, i) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={props.onClick(album)}>
            <AlbumThumb name={album.name} img={album.photos[0].src} id={i} key={i} />
        </div>
    );
});
```

You can then tweak your parent class to store the whole selected album, and display photos depending on it :

```
class ThankYou extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            selectedAlbum: null
        }
    }

    albumClicked = selectedAlbum => ev => {
        this.setState({ selectedAlbum })
    }

    render() {
        const { selectedAlbum } = this.state
        return (
            <>
                <Albums albums={data3} onClick={this.albumClicked} />
                {selectedAlbum && <Photos photos={data3.find(album => album.name === selectedAlbum.name)} />}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: TypeError: props.onClick is not a function
onClick
.../GalleryComponents/Albums.js:32
  29 | }
  30 | 
  31 | const AlbumThumb = (props) => (
> 32 |   <div  className="thumb" onClick={ev => {props.onClick()}}>
  33 |     <div className="thumbImgWrap">
  34 |       <img src={require('./GalleryImages/' + props.img)} alt={props.name} />
  35 |     </div>

Comment: Yes Edit Post is helpful!!! I have in at last question
if I want to filter albums, can I set it somewhere? as, for example, at a colleague above? would you suggest any other solution?

Comment: If I want to filter pictures belonging to an album, what should I do? in the Photos.js component add the appropriate filter? Can you make the right logic in Albums.js?

Comment: I edited the first post and methode filter there and I wonder if I can use it somehow, because when it filters and indicates the specific album ID it shows this photo album, however I wonder how to create dynamic matching photos for albums without indicating in the filter a specific ID I would like to indicate that before I had '1' instead of photos.id and then it showed all the pictures from all albums.

Comment: I wonder if I have to change the whole const photos in some function, whether to set another function before it or to the component of the GaleryPhotosVideos parent to add something in setState, here I have a problem.

Comment: your solution with the find method works and shows albums, while when I click on the album, erros in props.photos.map is not function

Comment: Weird, can you print out the selected album in that case ? and your data3 array to see what' going wrong

Comment: Alright I get the error, can you console log what I asked before in you program ?

Comment: if I understood you correctly, by checking in console.log (selectedAlbum) and clicking on the selected album, it shows me: 
`{id: "2", name: "Piłka nożna", photos: Array(3)}
id: "2"
name: "Piłka nożna"
photos: Array(3)
0: {id: "21", src: "pilkaNozna1.jpg", cap: "Piłka nożna1"}
1: {id: "22", src: "pilkaNozna2.jpeg", cap: "Piłka nożna2"}
2: {id: "23", src: "pilkaNozna3.jpg", cap: "Piłka nożna3"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object`

Comment: I know!!!! i change `{selectedAlbum && <Photos photos={data3.find(album => album.name === selectedAlbum.name)} />}` to  `{selectedAlbum && <Photos photos={data3.filter(album => album.name === selectedAlbum.name)} />}`  ---> resolving is change method find to filter!!!! 
I thanks your for your help was invaluable!!

Comment: Oh, alright, glad it could help out, so you're sending an array with ALL photos ?

Comment: No, after pressing the appropriate album, the photos assigned to him are displayed

Comment: ok, there is one phase of creating albums, now I'm going to combine another component, in which I will branch out albums thematically, i.e. sport, education, relaxation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Manage your data as state in an outer component as state. And pass it as props to both `Album` and `Photos`. Update photos from album component.

```
class Outer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            photos: [],
            albums: [
                {
                id: '1',
                name: "Siatkówka",
                photos: [
                    {
                        id: "11",
                        src: "siatkowka1.jpg",
                        cap: "Siatkówka"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "12",
                        src: "siatkowka2.jpg",
                        cap: "Siatkówka2"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "13",
                        src: "siatkowka3.jpg",
                        cap: "Siatkówka3"
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: '2',
                    name: "Piłka nożna",
                    photos:[
                        {
                            id: "21",
                            src: "pilkaNozna1.jpg",
                            cap: "Piłka nożna1"
                        },
                        {
                            id: "22",
                            src: "pilkaNozna2.jpeg",
                            cap: "Piłka nożna2"
                        },
                        {
                            id: "23",
                            src: "pilkaNozna3.jpg",
                            cap: "Piłka nożna3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    const updatePhotos = (albumId) => {
        // pass this function to album as prop and bind with each album. 
        const album = this.state.albums.filter((album) => album.id === albumId)
        this.setState({
            photos: album.photos
        })
    }
    render() {
        <>
            <Albums albums={this.state.albums} clickHandler={this.updatePhotos} />
            {this.state.photos ? <Photos photos={this.state.photos} /> : null}
        </>
    }
}
```

In `Albums`, call clickHandler with album id

```
<AlbumThumb name={album.name}
            img={album.photos[0].src} 
            id={i} 
            key={i}
            onClick={() => this.props.clickHandler(album.id)}  />
```

Comment: no errors, but it does not display photos from a particular album

Comment: `<Container>

    <ListGroup>
     <div>
      {this.state.albums.map(({ photos }) => (
       <React.Fragment>
        <li key={photos.id}>
        {photos.id} 
        </li>

        {photos.map((eachThing) =>
        <ul key={eachThing.id}>
         {eachThing.src}  | {eachThing.cap} | {eachThing.id}
        </ul>
        )}
       </React.Fragment>
      ))}
     </div>
    </ListGroup>
  </Container>`
When I created list for check this, then i show it's all allright but, when i Cliced albums not happens